# Where can I find insertion code?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I imported data from excel file into oracle sql developer. After having filled in all tables I tried to see the insertion code, but I couldn't. Can you tell me where I can find it?

Comment: Welcome. Could you give some additional detail - it's hard to tell what you have done and where you are stuck.

Comment: i want to seethe  insertion code something like this:                     INSERT INTO users

(first_name, last_name)

VALUES

('john', 'smith');

Comment: but i dont know where it is